# Regex to detect smart-alec spaces in words(!)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will stop the "forget" word.. Smart alecs are still getting away with:

```
"f o r g e t you", and
"f o r
g e t you" (using \r\n)
```

Before I captured the offending word with

`$(?<!(FORGET[\s]*))`

I am attempting to use `$(<!(F\s*O\s*R\s*G\s*E\s*T))` - with the thought process of \s* capturing white-space 0 or more times between the letters... Alas that does not work.  I hope I am not too far off, but I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything inherently wrong with your approach. It works fine in the browser, for instance... https://regexr.com/3sfrp

Comment: `if (Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", "").ToUpper().EndsWith("FORGET")`?

Comment: There will always be ways around this, so don't spend too much time on it.  There will also always be flaws. For example, my friends in Scunthorpe can't mention their home town when sending messages in GTA Online.  Neither can my Aunt Fanny or Uncle Dick say their own names!

Comment: I couldnt us the word "niggle" in a chat the other day cos apparently its too close to being racist... err... well to a dyslexic and a computer maybe, but to a dictionary.. no.

Comment: Best way to filter banned words - does not exist. It is either implies machine learning or some hacky heuristic mapping tables for each symbol.

Comment: Thanks everyone: I am using "FORGET" as an example, but the principal is that I have an illegal sequence in a ASCII message that our testers are an being clever with white space, newlines etc.  I am not trying to endlessly censor out swears.  I just need to stop that one sequence.

Comment: Whelp, looks like we'll have to swear in Chinese now :P

Answer (score 0):

One way to find banned words in chat rooms for example is to create dictionary of all possible representations of them (including morphological) AND to transform special characters/sequences such as '@' to 'a' or 'JI' то 'Л'.

Best way I found so far:

1. Perform transform of special sequences (@->a).
2. Concatenate alphabet-only characters together into one big line removing repeating characters (baaaaaaneeeedddd).
3. Build suffix tree from this merge.
4. Find banned sub-sequences in suffix tree.
5. Test this on 100 thousand of your messages.
6. Fix some frequent bugs.

It is fairly efficient and optimal validation and can be performed on client, also it is pretty hard to combine words in such way it will give false-positive hit.